# How can I specify the a custom width and height to the container Mason plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm using Mason plugin and it's seems annoying that everytime I give a custom width and height it will fail

```
#grid {
    width: 655px;
    height:188px;
    position: relative;
}
#gallery {
    width: 655px;
    height:188px;
        position: relative;
}
```

[image]

as seen in the pic the container is that size ,But the boxes size is too large to so it breaks the container and also gaps are found

using : https://github.com/DrewDahlman/Mason

the width and height required are W:655px X H:188px random image grid generator

as the plugin offer few info about how it works I can't get that work

Comment: If you are going to use a fixed width and height, then you don't really need JS at all. Just position everything where you want it with CSS. (Generally it's a bad idea to use fixed height if there is any text inside the boxes, though.)

Comment: the point is I want it to randomly select position and size the plugin will do that and fill missing gaps but still the issue of specifying a specific height is a missing ring